# How do I distinguish freeway onramps from offramps?

Tags: openstreetmap

Freeway entrances and exits are tagged as highway=motorway_link. However, for some analysis I'm doing, I need to distinguish between entrances ("on ramps") and exits ("off ramps").

Is there an automated way to do this with existing OSM tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the direction of the way or, if mapped, oneway=yes tags. By combining both, the direction of the motorway_links and the angle between highway=motorway_link and highway=motorway you should be able to calculate entrances and exits. Big angles (in direction of travel) should be exits, smaller ones should be entrances.

More accurate: Select the angle between the motorway **from** the direction of travel and its intersection with motorway_link.

[image]

Comment: The angle won't suffice if the highway=motorway_link consists of multiple ways. But an onramp will always lead *to* a highway=motorway and an offramp will always lead *from* an highway=motorway when looking at the way direction and the oneway=yes tag. Also keep in mind that on interchanges there are motorway_links leading both *from* and *to* motorways.